# Moleculer logger logging javascript instead of typescript stack

Tags: typescript, moleculer

I use Moleculer 0.14 with my `moleculer.config.ts` for the logger looking like this:

```
logger: {
    type: "Console",
    options: {
        level: process.env.LOGLEVEL || "debug",
        colors: true,
        moduleColors: true,
        formatter: "full",
        objectPrinter: null,
        autoPadding: true,
    },
}
```

I have enabled `sourceMap` in `tsconfig.json`

I have installed `source-map-support`, which i then import into the `index.ts.`

I use docker-compose for my services like this:

```
    my_service:
        image: my_image
        hostname: my_service
        command: ./node_modules/.bin/moleculer-runner --config=dist/moleculer.config.js
        networks:
            - my_network
        environment:
            SERVICES: dist/services/my_service
        restart: always
```

Stacktrace always references `js` files in my `dist` folder, even though I have `js.map` files generated.

How do you make logger, log `ts` files instead?